Notepad++ как удалить 1-2 пустые строки в начале каждого файла
Есть, скажем, 100 файлов и в каждом в начале 1-2 пустые строки - как их удалить? не все пустые, а только эти 1-2 вверху во всех файлах
<пусто>
<пусто>
текст

надо получить:
текст

и так в каждом файле, но только в начале

Можно использовать поиск и замена в файлах с регулярными выражениями.
Выбираем Поиск->Найти в файлах (или Ctrl+Shift+F).
Поле найти: \A^\r\n
Заменить на: оставляем пусто
Фильтры: если искать надо в определённых типах файлов, то указываем расширение файла
Папка: выбираем папка с файлами
Режим поиска: регулярные выражения
Нажимаем заменить в файлах и радуемся результату: Notepad++ удалит все начальные пустые строки в файлах.
Проверял на версии 8.6.8

спасибо вам большое) все получилось, вы мне очень помогли

У Notepad++ есть возможность записи макроса. После чего записанный макрос следует "проиграть" n-файлово раз.
Указанная вами операция может решаться также через поиск/замену. Там есть возможность расширить Search Mode:

Normal

Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x…)

Regular Expression


Думаю, что второй пункт подойдёт вам, а дальше применить этот поиск/замену на файлы. Подробнее о расширенном режиме поиска см. здесь

Ответ в котором нету ответа

@Kromster да, к сожалению мой ответ предполагает наличие ума
